# How to display Featured product on home page slider in Magento-GO?

Tags: magento, magento-go

i am new in magento-go

i have added in home page,

```
  {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id=my_cat_id template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but how can i change design to be set in featured product block slider?

if anyone knows, plz help me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the codes from "catalog/product/list.phtml" to a new phtml file.

You can then change the layout of that phtml as you wish.

your new block will be something like:

{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id=my_cat_id template="catalog/product/newPage.phtml"}}

Not sure if this is what you were after?

J